# Why my LinearLayout take space even If I set Visibility gone inside gridView?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I have a LinearLayout inside grid view which is default  set visibility GONE,
On a single button click I am showing that LinearLayout , Then on the another Button click I am also setting My LinearLayout visibility gone again . So the problem is the my layout is gone successfully but it's still taking space , I am stuck by this problem since last one day ,And also search all the solution but non of them worked for me,

My code is :-

This is the XML file that I am populating in Adapter:

grid_view_dash_item.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemName"
            style="@style/textColorBlack_14sp"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Check Engine" />

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgWacsItem"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/battery" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switchView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:theme="@style/SwitchTheme"
            android:visibility="gone" />


        <IncrementDecrementWidgetActivity
            android:id="@+id/number_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            app:textSize="18sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/addCommentLayout"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgAddItemComment"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/edit_icon" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switchViewNoShow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="-30dp"
            android:theme="@style/SwitchTheme"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextPopup"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="Enter Comment"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/closePopupBtn"
            style="@style/buttonRegular"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/default_button_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="OK" />
        </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pupUpWindowLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
       >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textEdit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="text" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code of Adapter:-

```
 GridViewWacsItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridViewWacsItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context mContext;
    List<WacsDashboardItemResponse.SubGroup.ItemArray> itemArray;

    public GridViewWacsItemAdapter(Context mContext, List<WacsDashboardItemResponse.SubGroup.ItemArray> itemArray) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.itemArray = itemArray;
    }

    @Override
    public GridViewWacsItemAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_view_dash_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final GridViewWacsItemAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (itemArray.get(position).responseType.responseTypeList.equalsIgnoreCase("CHOICE_LIST1")) {
            holder.switchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.number_button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.addCommentLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.switchViewNoShow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        } else if (itemArray.get(position).responseType.responseTypeList.equalsIgnoreCase("CHOICE_LIST2")) {

            holder.switchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.number_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.addCommentLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            holder.switchViewNoShow.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            holder.number_button.setRange(0, 4);
        }

        holder.imgWacsItem.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.progress_bar_default);  // image for loading...
        holder.imgWacsItem.setImageUrl(itemArray.get(position).icon, AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader());
        holder.itemName.setText(itemArray.get(position).itmeDesc);

        holder.number_button.setOnClickListener(new IncrementDecrementWidgetActivity.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String number = holder.number_button.getNumber();
                // Toast.makeText(mContext, "number " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

holder.closePopupBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        holder.textEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.textEdit.setText(holder.editTextPopup.getText().toString());
        holder.layoutEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
});
        holder.addCommentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked on View", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              holder.layoutEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemArray.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView itemName, textEdit;
        Switch switchView, switchViewNoShow;
        NetworkImageView imgWacsItem;
        IncrementDecrementWidgetActivity number_button;
        LinearLayout pupUpWindowLayout, addCommentLayout,layoutEdit;
        Button closePopupBtn;
         EditText editTextPopup;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            itemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            imgWacsItem = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgWacsItem);
            switchView = (Switch) itemView.findViewById(R.id.switchView);
            switchViewNoShow = (Switch) itemView.findViewById(R.id.switchViewNoShow);
            closePopupBtn=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.closePopupBtn);
            editTextPopup=(EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.editTextPopup);
            textEdit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textEdit);
            pupUpWindowLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pupUpWindowLayout);
            addCommentLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addCommentLayout);
            layoutEdit = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layoutEdit);
            layoutEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            number_button = (IncrementDecrementWidgetActivity) itemView.findViewById(R.id.number_button);

        }
    }

}
```

Any type of help appreciated by me:-
Thanks

Comment: Which LinearLayout is supposed to be hidden? Your layout has several

Comment: Thanks for response @Selali which layout has id layoutEdit

Comment: remove `android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"` in your code .

Comment: @KeLiuyue your solution did not work

Answer (score 0):

Put a background color for the layout and see if it is really gone. There may be other views taking up the space, not the LinearLayout you are looking for.

Comment: Does't help , I am saying my item successfully gone but blank space is maintain

Comment: I just tried the code, removed unnecessary drawables and items from the xml and made a quick test, and I guess [the code works](https://youtu.be/1CLhhXU_J1w).